# changing columns in select tag with fixed size

Tags: html, html-select

how to create select list box in html with specific columns number?

```
<select name="test" size="2">
     <option value="test1">test1</option>
     <option value="test2">test2</option>
     <option value="test3">test3</option>
     <option value="test4">test4</option>
</select>
```

i want to see this select box, with two rows and two columns.

Comment: Select doesn't let you make columns, you'll need two of them

Comment: my work quickly done with this tag. and it's easiest way for me. i don't want use table

Answer (score 2):

As [@Mimisbrunnr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284731/mimisbrunnr) correctly pointed out, the [`<select>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6) tag does **not** provide the ability to use columns.  Rows... no problem, just set the `size` attribute to `2`.

About your "columns" issue, I'd suggest looking into some [select-replacement scripts](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/). Maybe you can find or customize one to meet your needs.

Also, consider changing your UI approach.  As [@Gabriel Belingueres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/979590/gabriel-belingueres) mentioned, maybe you can use a table with radio inputs. Trust me, it doesn't get easier or quicker than tables.